# Writing Regex According to [ char

Tags: java, regex

I have string something like this:

```
10:11:22 [UTP][ROX][ID:32424][APP STR]
```

I want to seperate each them of. How can I do it with regex?

I want to get seperately "`10:11:22`", "`UTP`", "`ROX`", "`ID:32424`", "`APP STR`" as strings.

Comment: separate each of what?

Comment: Can you split on regex `/\]? \[/` ? Then trim the last ] off.

Comment: It's helpful to know what to expect in each section of this. `10:11:22` looks like a time, should we assume `[UTP]` are always upper-case characters, and `[ID:` is static, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be your macthing parttern: `/\[([^\]]+)/g`

Working demo @ [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/jA7aJ7)

Working Java demo:

```
public class Main {
    private static final String REGEX = "\\[([^\\]]+)";
    private static final String INPUT = "10:11:22 [UTP][ROX][ID:32424][APP STR]";

    private static Pattern pattern;
    private static Matcher matcher;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(INPUT);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I can think of, with the drawback that it will create a blank final entry, is this:

```
"10:11:22 [UTP][ROX][ID:32424][APP STR]".split("[\[\]]+")
```

That will return you an array as this:

```
["10:11:22",
 "UTP",
 "ROX",
 "ID:32424",
 "APP STR",
 ""]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want regex to do the job. Then try the below,

```
(?:^([^\s]*)|\[([^]]*)\])
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qV0kZ8)

All the strings you want are stored separately in groups.